# Two different forms are loading at startup

Tags: c#

Found this nice code to start the app minimized at windows startup and it works fine.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    if (args.Length == 1 && (args[0] == "/StartMinimized" || args[0] == "-minimized"))
    {
        form1.Visible = true;
        form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        Application.Run(form1);
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Run(form1);
    }
```

the problem is that if I launch the app from the start menu a different instance of form loads and when the computer starts then a different one.

If I open the app from the start menu, save text in text box then it is different from the one that launches at windows startup.

If I use

```
Application.Run(new Form1());

form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Then I get form1 does not exist in the current context.
Is there any way to load the main form?

Comment: declare `form1` as a variable.

Comment: When you open the app from the start menu, does that pass the argument /StartMinimized or -minimized?

Comment: So what is your objective? Have just one form open/minimized? Pass data from the new form to the one already existing and closing the new one? or .....

Comment: My objective to start only the main form instance, windows startup launches a different form than the one launched from start menu. https://github.com/saudiqbal/SaudsGoogleDomainsDynamicDNSUpdater/blob/master/SaudsGoogleDomainsDynamicDNSUpdater/Program.cs